# totals sort of custom added row in my account order view

Tags: module, magento-1, orders, extensions, totals

I have problem with sort custom added row in totals.

I successfully sort new row in cart and checkout page with this in my moduele config.xml

```
   <default>
        <sales>
            <totals_sort>
                <rowtotal>20</rowtotal>
            </totals_sort>
        </sales>
  </default>
```

Also with success sort new row in pdf invoice with tag `<sort_order>` in my module config.xml

```
    <pdf>
    <totals>
      <rowtotal translate="title">
        <title>Ukupno s popustom</title>
        <source_field>rowtot_alamount</source_field>
        <model>Devpassion_Rowtotal_Model_Pdf_Total_Totalpdf</model>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>0</display_zero>
        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
      </rowtotal>
    </totals>
</pdf>
```

I don't have idea how to sort this new row in My orders view and email order view.

Comment: The problem with your updating <default> in the config xml is that if somebody ever saves the settings on the System > Config > Sales screen your updates will be lost. You can, and should, update this from within Magento configuration yourself.

Comment: ok. But where I can find my new custom added row in Magento configuration System > Config > Sales ?

Answer (score 1):

An answer on this question on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507210/magento-new-order-email-template-totals

[And classylama wrote a whole blog series about this I'm unable to sum up](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-example)